# Share an image and a link to my android app using Facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook

In my camera app for Android i would like to share a photo taken by the user to the user's facebook wall. I would like it has:

1. a text description written by the user (like in a shareDialog)
2. the image taken with my camera app
3. the link to the image itself in the album (to swipe to the previously uploaded ones)
4. some text (caption+description) about my app
5. a link to my app (with icon?) in google play

Here's a picture of what i want: (tweet-to-facebook posts are very similar to this, so i think it can be done!)

[image]

How to achieve this?
Should i use Open Graph?
I tried following developers.facebook tutorials, but i failed!! i think samples are buggy! It's very frustrating...

Please help, i need someone to show me the right way!

**EDIT**

actually this is my code, no foto is shown:

```
private void shareWithFacebookOpenGraph(String pathToImage) {
    Log.i("SHARE", "1. share with OpenGraph");  
    OpenGraphObject photo = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("myapp:photo");
    photo.setProperty("title", "MyApp Photo");
    photo.setProperty("image", "http://play.google.com/to_my_app_launcher_icon");
    photo.setProperty("url", "http://play.google.com/to_my_app");
    photo.setProperty("description", "Image taken with myApp for Android");

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(new File(pathToImage));

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("photo", photo);

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "myapp:take", "photo")
        //.setImageAttachmentFilesForObject("image", files, true)  // Error: image is not a property
        //.setImageAttachmentFilesForAction(files, true)        // Error sharing pictue: null
        //.setImageAttachmentFilesForObject("photo", files, true) // can't create Collection (?!?!)
        .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

Comment: Hi..@j,c I am also looking for the same and facing the issues as you are. Please let me know if you solved this.

Comment: @AndiM sorry, nothing worked for me, too frustrating!! i decided to focus my attention elsewhere, maybe I'll retry one day

Comment: is there any way to use both with same time image and URL.