# FacebookGraphObjectException: Can't create collection from java.lang.string

Tags: android, facebook

In my android app i'm trying to share an Open Graph including an object and an action.
In my facebook app i added a story: `action="take"` and `object="photo"` (is this ok?).

When i try to add an image to the object in the OG i get above error.

This is my code:

```
private void shareWithFacebookOpenGraph(String pathToImage) {
    Log.i("SHARE", "1. share with OpenGraph");  
    OpenGraphObject photo = OpenGraphObject.Factory.createForPost("myapp:photo");
    photo.setProperty("title", "MyApp Photo");
    photo.setProperty("image", "http://play.google.com/to_my_app_launcher_icon");
    photo.setProperty("url", "http://play.google.com/to_my_app");
    photo.setProperty("description", "Image taken with myApp for Android");

    List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();
    files.add(new File(pathToImage));

    OpenGraphAction action = GraphObject.Factory.create(OpenGraphAction.class);
    action.setProperty("photo", photo);

    FacebookDialog shareDialog = new FacebookDialog.OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder(this, action, "myapp:take", "photo")
        .setImageAttachmentFilesForObject("photo", files, true) // **Error**
        .build();
    uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
}
```

here's the logcat:

```
08-12 04:26:48.780: mypackage.myapp: fatal error : Can't create Collection from java.lang.String
08-12 04:26:48.780: com.facebook.FacebookGraphObjectException: Can't create Collection from java.lang.String
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory.coerceValueToExpectedType(GraphObject.java:371)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.proxyGraphObjectGettersAndSetters(GraphObject.java:675)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.model.GraphObject$Factory$GraphObjectProxy.invoke(GraphObject.java:523)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at $Proxy2.getImage(Native Method)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog$OpenGraphDialogBuilderBase.updateObjectAttachmentUrls(FacebookDialog.java:1386)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog$OpenGraphDialogBuilderBase.setImageAttachmentFilesForObject(FacebookDialog.java:1364)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog$OpenGraphActionDialogBuilder.setImageAttachmentFilesForObject(FacebookDialog.java:1)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at mypackage.myactivity.shareWithFacebookOpenGraph(EnhancedCameraPreviewActivity.java:3247)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at mypackage.myactivity.access$155(EnhancedCameraPreviewActivity.java:3224)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at mypackage.myactivity$89.onClick(EnhancedCameraPreviewActivity.java:3184)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-12 04:26:48.780:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What am i doing wrong?
Maybe i'm messing up some strings in the story, facebook tutorial is awful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already setting an image in the photo object. Remove that line if you're going to be adding images as an attachment later.

Comment: Oh, thanx, i understand. But can i add an image for the action (for example, my app's launcher icon) AND another for the object (a user taken photo)? If i use `.setImageAttachmentFilesForAction(files, true)` i get "Error sharing pictue: null"

Comment: The error sharing picture:null was due to a missing NativeAppCallContentProvider in manifest. Anyway i'm still not able to layout my open graph the way i want, please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247349